# this.type alternative for IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I know this has been asked many times before, but i still can't seem to find an answer.

I am trying to reference an object using the this.type property. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer, and breaks all my JS.

for example, i wish to reference - 
this.type
for a  field, and be able to change it to this.type = 'text'.

What alternatives/workarounds can i use for this?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: What this.type property?

Comment: If you don't post the code in question nobody will have any idea what you're talking about. Referencing the "type" property of an `<input>` DOM node does in fact work just fine in Internet Explorer, way back to IE6 at least.

Comment: you are correct. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the "type" of an `<input>` element in IE. You just can't; it won't let you. You can however remove the element and add a new one in its place.